# Kimsufi API setup

Tags: php, ovh

Has anyone had any experience in setting up a Kimsufi API using PHP?

I am trying to configure but i am getting this error

```
errorCode":"NOT_CREDENTIAL","httpCode":"403 Forbidden","message":"This credential does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No need to spam the Internet:

- http://zanswers.com/question/5664a0558ead0eec058bf0b2/kimsufi-api-setup
- http://phpanswerz.com/content-34064052-kimsufi-api-setup.html
- http://www.codegur.net/34064052/kimsufi-api-setup
- http://quabr.com/34064052/kimsufi-api-setup

Anyway, assuming you are really desperate about this problem, ovh has a brilliant support and you can just call it. Also according to Kimsufi I think, better check out if Kimsufi has it's own support first.